# How to use angularjs to order by custom field?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to create a html table to use angular js to display the user result, it has three status: "Pass", "In Process" and "Fail".
Here is my code:

```
angular.module('myExam', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.Exam_result =
          [{name:'John', result:'Fail', age:10},
           {name:'Mary', result:'Pass', age:19},
           {name:'Mike', result:'In Process', age:21},
           {name:'Adam', result:'In Process', age:35},
           {name:'Julie',result:'Fail', age:29}];
      $scope.predicate = 'age';
      $scope.reverse = true;
      $scope.order = function(predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
      };
    }]);
```

---

```
<body ng-app="myExam"> 
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <table class="Exam" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a href="" ng-click="order('name')">Name</a>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <a href="" ng-click="order('result')">Phone Number</a>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <a href="" ng-click="order('age')">Age</a>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'age'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="Exam in Exam_result | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
      <td>{{Exam.name}}</td>
      <td>{{Exam.result}}</td>
      <td>{{Exam.age}}</td>
    </tr>   
  </table>   
  <hr>
</body>
```

I hope the user can click the Status and sort it like so, instead of alphabetically:
First 'Pass', second 'Fail', third 'In process'

Here is my link:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9334apr/9/)

Comment: there is no field status in your fiddle

Comment: THANKS , http://jsfiddle.net/v9334apr/6/

Comment: what do you mean by thanks? still i see no status

Comment: OK now?? http://jsfiddle.net/v9334apr/9/

Comment: now also the same only result column is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use smart-table has great documentation and easy to use.

http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/